# Custom fonts in Google Colaboratory matplotlib charts

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, google-colaboratory

Using custom fonts in matplotlib locally involves storing the `.ttf`s in the `matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/` folder, then calling `mpl.font_manager._rebuild()`, then setting `mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif']`.

Is there any way to do this in Google Colaboratory, where it doesn't seem that this `ttf` folder is accessible?

For example, I'd like to use the [Roboto font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto). After installing, this would be invoked using `mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Roboto'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ttf` folder is here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
```

So you want to download the `ttf` there, e.g.:

```
!wget https://github.com/Phonbopit/sarabun-webfont/raw/master/fonts/thsarabunnew-webfont.ttf -P /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf

matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
matplotlib.rc('font', family='TH Sarabun New')
```

### update 2019-12

`_rebuild()` no longer works. Here's another method which still works.

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

!wget https://github.com/Phonbopit/sarabun-webfont/raw/master/fonts/thsarabunnew-webfont.ttf
fm.fontManager.ttflist += fm.createFontList(['thsarabunnew-webfont.ttf'])
matplotlib.rc('font', family='TH Sarabun New')
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's a colab where I show it working: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15kcRpv9wkLO2vxWux_gzobVcPuIoJ14r

Comment: I edited to have the full answer here. When do you need the font to also be in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`, as in your [gist](https://gist.github.com/korakot/9d7f5db632351dc92607fdec72a4953f)?

Comment: I'm not sure why I did that. I guess I tried many things till it worked and stopped there. BTW, what's the different between `.rc(..)` and setting `rcParams`? When should I use one or the other?

Comment: OK cool. From https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams, `rcParams` seems to be the default approach, but: "The `matplotlib.rc()` command can be used to modify multiple settings in a single group at once, using keyword arguments:"

Comment: This is no longer working: `findfont: Font family ['Roboto'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.` https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15kcRpv9wkLO2vxWux_gzobVcPuIoJ14r

Comment: I got the same problem a few weeks ago. I've updated the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to add a full, succinct answer that currently works.

```py
# Download fonts of choice. Here we download Open Sans variants to
# the current directory.
# It's not necessary to download to the share or matplotlib folders:
# /usr/share/fonts/truetype
# /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
!wget 'https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'
!wget 'https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-Light.ttf'
!wget 'https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf'
!wget 'https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/opensans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'
```

```py
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm, pyplot as plt

# Pick up any fonts in the current directory.
# If you do end up downloading the fonts to /usr/share/fonts/truetype,
# change this to: fm.findSystemFonts()
font_files = fm.findSystemFonts('.')

# Go through and add each to Matplotlib's font cache.
for font_file in font_files:
    fm.fontManager.addfont(font_file)

# Use your new font on all your plots.
plt.rc('font', family='Open Sans')
```

Note, a few times this didn't work properly and the requested font wasn't displayed (even though no error or warning was shown). If that happens, try factory resetting your Colab runtime and running again.

Answer (score 2):

When matplotlib 3.2 is released, it will be easier.

```py
# For now we must upgrade to 3.2 rc first
# !pip install -U --pre matplotlib  
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.font_manager.fontManager.addfont('thsarabunnew-webfont.ttf')
mpl.rc('font', family='TH Sarabun New')
```

Comment: Neat, though this still requires downloading the file. Passing the url doesn't work; I filed [matplotlib#15936](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15936) to request this.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add my solutions as another reference:

1. **Change the seaborn style**
   I would strongly recommend this approach as changing the font family can be very troublesome and inconvenient per seaborn design (many of the posts are no longer working on my end in 2022/05). So if you just want to get rid of the stupid default font in matplotlib and seaborn and is OK with **Arial**, go and type

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.style as style 
style.use('seaborn-deep')
```

2. **Changing the font type** (borrowed from top answers and tested myself. Restarting the runtime several times if it is not working as expected)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm, pyplot as plt

!wget https://github.com/trishume/OpenTuringCompiler/blob/master/stdlib-sfml/fonts/Times%20New%20Roman.ttf
!wget https://github.com/matomo-org/travis-scripts/blob/master/fonts/Arial.ttf 

font_files = fm.findSystemFonts()

# Go through and add each to Matplotlib's font cache.
for font_file in font_files:
    fm.fontManager.addfont(font_file)

fm.fontManager.ttflist += fm.createFontList(['Times New Roman.ttf'])

# Use your new font on all your plots.
plt.rc('font', family='serif')


t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.show()
```

**Updates on 2022/06/08**: Method 1 sometimes doesn't work out in Colab, but it works on the local Jupyter Notebook. It seems that explicitly installing and adding the font types is the only way if you want to customize font types on Colab.