# Not able to used "Times New Roman" font in google colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab, and I'm trying to use the "Times New Roman" font for my matplotlib plotting. since the ttf file in google colab is located in`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf` so what i did is downloaded the ttf file for "Times New Roman" from `https://github.com/trishume/OpenTuringCompiler/blob/master/stdlib-sfml/fonts/Times%20New%20Roman.ttf` and ran a command `!wget https://github.com/trishume/OpenTuringCompiler/blob/master/stdlib-sfml/fonts/Times%20New%20Roman.ttf -P /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf` which basically downloded the tff file in the font folder of matplotlib in google colab.

Now after this when I'm trying to use `matplotlib.font_manager.findfont('Times New Roman')` it's giving me an error which is shown below. and hence I'm unable to use that font in the plotting.

So I'm unable to find what went wrong as I personally checked and found tff file for the above-mentioned font.

Please help

```
!wget https://github.com/trishume/OpenTuringCompiler/blob/master/stdlib-sfml/fonts/Times%20New%20Roman.ttf -P /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
font_manager.findfont('Times New Roman')
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1241: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Times New Roman'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810908/custom-fonts-in-google-colaboratory-matplotlib-charts. I admittedly don't know much of anything about Google colab, but it seems like a similar question.

Comment: I've used the same approach but it's not working

Comment: At least from what you had written in your question, you had not done the rebuild step.

Comment: sorry I did that but forgot to mention here

Answer (score 5):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Tried it right now, but it gave me `WARNING:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: Font family ['serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.`

Comment: This code works for me, perhaps Google Colab got an update

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']
```

The solution posted by @Awal worked for me after installing matplotlib to version 1.5.3 and back to version 3.2.2

```
! pip uninstall -qq matplotlib
! pip install -qq matplotlib==1.5.3
! pip uninstall -qq matplotlib
! pip install -qq matplotlib==3.2.2
```