# Trying to change Google Colab font family to Arial

Tags: python, fonts, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use the Arimo-font in Google Colab. I´ve been using some code that I got from a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65841091/18129402):

```
 from matplotlib import font_manager as fm, pyplot as plt

 ### Downloading Arial-like font from googles github page
 !wget https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/
 f6d3dee82ebbc3bec83e78e200f6d0b62a9d702e/apache/arimo/Arimo%5Bwght%5D.ttf
 
 font_files = fm.findSystemFonts('.')

 # Go through and add each to Matplotlib's font cache.
  for font_file in font_files:
    fm.fontManager.addfont(font_file)

  Use your new font on all your plots.
  plt.rc('font', family='Open Sans')
```

But when I do this, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d9d8c3099d94> in <module>()
      8 # Go through and add each to Matplotlib's font cache.
      9 for font_file in font_files:
---> 10     fm.fontManager.addfont(font_file)
     11 
     12 # Use your new font on all your plots.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in addfont(self, path)
   1011             self.afmlist.append(prop)
   1012         else:
-> 1013             font = ft2font.FT2Font(path)
   1014             prop = ttfFontProperty(font)
   1015             self.ttflist.append(prop)

RuntimeError: In FT2Font: Can not load face.  Unknown file format.
```

What is this error and how can I remove it?